# Maps V2 Marker pressed states

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

In Maps V2, how can I set a pressed state to a Marker?

The setIcon() method takes a BitmapDescriptor; I can't see a way to pass an XML selector which would give a pressed and selected state.

Is the only way to achieve this to override the OnMarkerClickListener and change the image programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to change the icon for the duration of `Marker` being pressed as of API v2 version 3.1.36.

For the selected state, you may work it around by using `OnMarkerClickListener`, setting some icon, remembering the reference to this marker and changing it back to normal when another marker is clicked or some other action occures, e.g. `onMapClick` or `onMapLongClick` is called.