# Clustering map markers on zoom out and unclustering on zoom in

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I am using the [Google Map Android clustering Utitlity](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering#custom) With Google Maps v2 play services.

I am not getting the behavior I expected. As you can see in the two images below, when zoomed in I can see a cluster of 20 and a single marker up an to the left, but when i zoom out til they are on top of each other i am not seeing them cluster.. the 20 cluster still says 20 and not 21?

[image]

[image]

Is that expected behavior?  Is there a way can make the cluster show 21 instead of 20+

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is default behavior specified in [`DefaultClasterRenderer#onBeforeClusterRendered()`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/view/DefaultClusterRenderer.java#L698):

```
/**
 * Called before the marker for a Cluster is added to the map.
 * The default implementation draws a circle with a rough count of the number of items.
 */
protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<T> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    int bucket = getBucket(cluster);
    BitmapDescriptor descriptor = mIcons.get(bucket);
    if (descriptor == null) {
        mColoredCircleBackground.getPaint().setColor(getColor(bucket));
        descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mIconGenerator.makeIcon(getClusterText(bucket)));
        mIcons.put(bucket, descriptor);
    }
    // TODO: consider adding anchor(.5, .5) (Individual markers will overlap more often)
    markerOptions.icon(descriptor);
}
```

Note that text for the marker is chosen based on the `bucket`, rather than exact number of items in `cluster`

The quick fix for that would be to modify descriptor creation to be something like:

```
descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(mIconGenerator.
                                                 makeIcon(cluster.getSize());
```

Of course you can implement your custom `ClasterRenderer` and provide it to the [`ClusterManager`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.java#L74). In this way you will be in charge of rendering of your markers, but if you want to just change the `"20+"` to `"21"` - I would go with first approach

**EDIT:**

Addressing question asked in comments:
If you want to increase/decrease distance threshold for grouping items - you can modify [default algorithm](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/clustering/algo/NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm.java#L35) used for clustering. Just play with this constant (in your case should be smaller):

```
public static final int MAX_DISTANCE_AT_ZOOM = 100; // essentially 100 dp.
```

But the correct fix would be to take into account Marker bitmap size rather than constant value. I assume [Mr. Broadfood](https://twitter.com/broady) left that as a homework to enthusiasts :)

```
private Bounds createBoundsFromSpan(Point p, double span) {
    // TODO: Use a span that takes into account the visual size of the marker, not just its
    // LatLng.
    double halfSpan = span / 2;
    return new Bounds(
            p.x - halfSpan, p.x + halfSpan,
            p.y - halfSpan, p.y + halfSpan);
}
```

Comment: Quick side question Pavel as you seem to have experience with this utility.  I noticed that its grouping markers that are not exactly on top of each other in the current zoom level.  there seems to be little documentation on this utility.  How can i set the range of how close markers are before they group/cluster

Comment: Thanks again Pavel, do you have any experience with creating and handling Cluster/ClusterItem(s) selected state?  the render creates an icon it seems, and i want to be able to change the view and pass a dyanmic image into that view, when a given item or cluster is selected, as well as change all the unselected back to their unselected/original state.. i have looked through the library and cant seem to find where the selected/unselected state is..

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999827/maps-v2-marker-pressed-states)

Comment: Yeah I saw that but that is not taking into account the cluster utility.. I'll dive and see what I find.  Not much in the way of documentation on this library

Comment: I tried this solution, but not is significantly good render, but is a great solution, How I can improve render ??

Answer (score 5):

You can change your minimum cluster size. By Default minimum cluster size is 4 defined in map-utils library as below.

```
    /**
     * If cluster size is less than this size, display individual markers.
     */
    private int mMinClusterSize = 4;

    /**
     * Determine whether the cluster should be rendered as individual markers or a cluster.
     */
    protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster<T> cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize() > mMinClusterSize;
    }
```

Or you can override shouldRenderAsCluster method in your extended DefaultClusterRenderer class as below:

```
@Override
protected boolean shouldRenderAsCluster(Cluster cluster) {
    // Always render clusters.
    return cluster.getSize() > 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but for those still using Pavel's excellent answer, also make sure that you change these two lines of code

```
BitmapDescriptor descriptor = mIcons.get(cluster.getSize());
...
mIcons.put(bucket, descriptor);
```

replacing bucket like so:

```
BitmapDescriptor descriptor = mIcons.get(cluster.getSize());
...
mIcons.put(cluster.getSize(), descriptor);
```

Otherwise clusters will be rounding to the nearest bucket size when merging/separating resulting in inaccurate bucket sizes.

Kind of an obvious fix, but very easy to miss if you aren't paying attention to the exact values of your data.

For anyone struggling:

The simplest way to implement Pavel's answer while retaining Google's rendering algorithm is to download the default renderer (as linked in Correct Answer), modify the code, and set it as a custom renderer for your ClusterManager. The library is not friendly to external modification / overwriting, and it's a colossal pain in the butt to only overwrite this segment, because it uses so many other private methods and variables.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who is struggling to do the same..
in your custom renderer override these two function as below
    @Override
    protected int getBucket(Cluster cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize();
    }

```
@Override
protected String getClusterText(int bucket) {
    return String.valueOf(bucket);
}
```