# Android marker Clustering So slow

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have problem with [Google Maps Android Marker Clustering Utility](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering), that reorganize markers from map in clusters. In my app I have 1200 markers and clustering is very slow.

Here is my code:

```
Into my for (json){
    GoogleLocationCustom classe; // note : GoogleLocationCustom  extends ClusterItem
    mClusterManager.addItem(classe);
}
```

After for (json) :

```
mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(mClusterManager);
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(mClusterManager);
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new OwnIconRendered(GoogleMapActivaFind.this, mMap, mClusterManager));
mClusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener(new ClusterManager.OnClusterItemClickListener<GoogleLocationCustom>() {...}
```

Comment: you can use :  not is a best but is something...,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21267775/clustering-map-markers-on-zoom-out-and-unclustering-on-zoom-in

Comment: have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have some first hand experience with this for something close. It is literally just you have too much stuff as you suspected. I had to cut it down to 200-300. Luckily for us, it didn't really matter much. Test it on your devices with different amount and see what the limit was, but we noticed slowness at about 300.